# Clicking Visual Studio 2015 Error List does not open the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have experienced several times while using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition that double-clicking the files in the the Error List does not open the file as usual. It happens for some files only. When I click ctrl-, to open a file and write the same filename I get a popup-error saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Anyone know why this happens or if it is a known bug in VS2015? Resharper is installed but currently suspended but perhaps there is a relation there.

It is very annoying so any help is appreciated.

Further specification of my environment:

```
Windows 10 
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)   14.1.20203.0
ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
Azure App Service Tools v2.7.1   14.0.11112.0
Common Azure Tools   1.5
JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2   Build 104.0.20151218.120627
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
NuGet Package Manager   3.4.1
PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
TestDriven.Net   3
TypeScript   1.7.6.0
```

Comment: Repairing installation and trying again may help.

Comment: I finally Repaired my Visual Studio and stopped using Resharper. So far the problem has not appeared again.

Comment: If ReSharper is suspended, it isn't even loaded into memory, so the issue wouldn't be related.

Comment: I face the same problem again. I have completely cleaned up my machine by uninstalling VS2015 and re-installing VS2015 with Update 3 (Resharper is not started yet). The problem re-appears now. Does anybody have any suggestions? This is really annoying .

Comment: Do you use `Build + Intellisense` or `Build Only` in the `Show issues generated` drop down list? I have the same issue, and looks like it affects only `Build` errors, so if I switch to `Intellisense Only` this gives excepted result - clicking works. Btw, did you find any solution?

Comment: @Konard No unfortunately I never figured out what caused this issue. It normally helps to restart Visual Studio.